# How to print decreasing odd numbers starting from scanf input integer in C?

Tags: c, while-loop

If you input even numbers, only the odd numbers will be printed until it reaches 0. (0 will not be printed). For example, if you input 10, the output would be 9, 7, 5, 3, 1.

This is what I came up with. I'm wondering what should I decrement x by to get the desired output.

```
int x;
scanf("%d", &x);
while (x >= 0) {
  printf("%d", x);
  x = x - 2;
}
```

Comment: while input>0 .... ???

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could decrement the given number by one each time, and check its remainder modulus 2, or you could decrement it by two if starting value is odd and keep printing until you reach 1. There are lots of ways to obtain what you seek, post some code though.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service

Comment: You may want to test if the remainder after dividing `x` by `2` is `0` or `1`... and decrement `x` if it is `0` (if the remainder is `0` the original `x` is even)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x, n;


printf("Give N: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("odd numbers from 1 to %d are: \n", n);
x=n;
while(x<=n && x>0)
{
    if(x%2!=0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    x--;
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 5):

> I'm wondering what should I decrement x by to get the desired output.

Subtracting 2 is fine, as long as you always start from an odd number. So you could change the loop into something like this:

```
for ( int i = x % 2 ? x : x - 1; // Is x odd? good. 
                                 // Otherwise, start from the previous one.
      i > 0;
      i -= 2 ) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: do you know the statement `x -= x % 2;` to make `x` even?  If you subtract a value `x` its module `n` residue, you get a full multiple of `n` :)  Why complicate so much the initial `for` expression?

Comment: ...in the case of even numbers, you can do `x &= ~1;`  (a bit mask with all ones except the least significant bit to set it to zero)

Comment: @LuisColorado Well, my understanding of the problem statement is that given an input of 10 (even) the output should be 9 7 5 3 2 1, the same as if the input were 9. So we need to make x *odd* and I don't think (IMHO) that `x += ~(x % 2);` would be more readable, but your mileage may vary ;)

Comment: Is not more readable if you don't know C, of course.  At least is more compact, and it is also more efficient (well, compilers today can do marvels with your code)  Anyway, it was not a critique (and less a critique in the sense you have taken it) but just a comment.  In the first comment, I use `x -= x % 2;`, which is far more readable than your example, and far clearer.  But I detect some intention to just counterattack me.  I'll not continue this discussion more than this.  My apologies for having offended you with my comment.

Comment: @LuisColorado There seems to be a misunderstanding (I'm not a native english speaker and that happens a lot more than I'd like). I wasn't offended at all and I'm sorry if my wording let you belive I was attacking you personally.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not a native english speaker, and probably I got defensive unintentionally.  My apologies also for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was *almost* correct (indeed, it is a pity that you have selected as the correct question such a bad response)  I will show you where is your error:

```
int x;
scanf("%d", &x);

if (x % 2 == 0) /* if the number is even */
    x = x - 1;  /* decrement it to convert it in an odd number */

while (x >= 0) {
  printf("%d", x);
  x = x - 2;
}
```

The thing is that you start your question with exactly that assert (*if you input even numbers...*)

Another problem is that you don't say what should happen when you introduce an odd number.  Anyway, the code printed it, and all the odd numbers until we reach 0.

Why your code is better than the selected one?  because your code only wastes time in the loop with the valid results, and doesn't get into the loop to decide that it has nothing to do.  This saves a lot of loop executions (almost half of them) which, if your number is very large, can do your program a lot more efficient.

Comment: @gen, I'll give you an upvote to your question because your _almost_ solution was better than some of the responses voted here (including the selected one)